# how to handle subtraction in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have registration form, where a user can enter her
name,email,dateofBirth,mobile Number. I want to calculate the users
age. If the user is 21 old he is able to register with us unless he cannot able to register. I have already created custom validation, and I pass the validation in my model class. But I am not able to calculate the age and use the logic for 21 year. I created dynamic form.

SignUp.html

```
<div class="content-area-container page-ath-wrap" th:object="${advertisement}">
    <div class="page-ath-content container-fluid">
        <div class="page-ath-form">
            <div class="page-ath-heading">
                <!--                <h3 th:text="*{reward_amount}">Congrats! You just earned $5 off your next beer.</h3>-->
                <h3 th:text="*{form_title}"></h3>
                <!--                <p>Enter your info to claim the reward!</p>-->
                <p th:text="*{form_description}"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="singup-form">
                <form id="form_signup">
                    <input id="id" th:field="*{id}" type="hidden"/>
                    <div th:each="item,iterStat : *{form}" >
<!--                        <label th:label="${str.getLabel()}" th:type="${str.getType()}" th:text="${str.value}" ></label>-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label th:for="${item.name}" th:text="${item.label}"></label>
                            <div th:if="${item.validation == 'dob'}" >
                                <input class="form-control" th:id="${item.name}" th:name="${item.name}" th:placeholder="${item.placeholder}" th:required="${item.required}"
                                       th:type="${item.type}" th:attr="max=${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'MM-dd-yyyy')}"/>
                            </div>
                            <div th:unless="${item.validation == 'dob'}" >
                                <input class="form-control" th:id="${item.name}" th:name="${item.name}" th:placeholder="${item.placeholder}" th:required="${item.required}"
                                       th:type="${item.type}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
```

Advertisement.kt

```
class Advertisement(val media: ArrayList<MEDIA>? = null)

class Form(
    val type:String="",
    val required:Boolean,
    val label:String="",
    val placeholder:String="",
    val name:String="",
    val value:String="",
    val validation:String="",
    val min:Int,
)
```

Comment: You can only do that with javascript, else you would need a form submit to set the field and re-render the form.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer suggested you can do it with javascript.

You can make use of this jQuery validation [API](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

And add a custom validation method like so:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("olderThan21", function(value, element) { 
 return //age calculation logic if true-> validation pass
//if false->validation error }
, "You must be 21+ to subscribe");
```

In case that the validation isn't passed satisfactory this will prevent the form from submitting.